# Convert Date String to Full Date

Tags: php, mysql, date, formatting

I'm returning a date from my database and converting it to a formatted date, but instead of showing the full month it says "Apr" instead. Is there a way I can make it show the full month and not just the abbreviation?

**Code**

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_date)))
    $date[] = date("M d",strtotime($row[0]));
```

And this is what my DB is returning `2012-04-25 22:07:35`, the date function return this `Apr 25`

Comment: mysql has its own date format function it would be better to use that than php. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format should be,

```
while(($row = mysql_fetch_array($query_date)))
    $date[] = date("F d",strtotime($row[0]));
```

Here, you can get all formats..

http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ss/php_functions_3.htm

Answer (score 0):

Use `F` http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php

```
$date[] = date("F d",strtotime($row[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

shoule be `F` not `M`...

```
$date[] = date("F d",strtotime($row[0]));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.date.php, it can give you the information you need about the date format

in your case, you need to change

```
$date[] = date("M d",strtotime($row[0]));
```

to

```
$date[] = date("F d",strtotime($row[0]));
```

"F" returns Full month (January through December).